# Answer ban correction

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I am banned from writing answers, and all the answers I wrote, the question has been already been deleted by someone. 
Actually they were homework questions and I answered them, so it is not acceptable that I get banned right?
What can I do?

Comment: It's implied in the meta post that writing good answers might be able to get you out of a question ban, so maybe asking good questions can get you out of an answer ban?

Comment: You can see "https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th"

Answer (score 15):

Simple: don't write answers to questions that are going to get deleted.

Homework questions get deleted for a reason: we don't want them here. If you answer poor-quality homework questions, you are nullifying the effect of the homework policy and you are providing an incentive for the users whose questions you answer (as well as others who see that those askers got their queries resolved) to post more poor-quality homework questions. That brings the site's content quality down, and it makes it harder for us to retain the expert users that provide the high-quality answers that make this site great.

So: you've posted a bunch of answers that negatively impact the site's quality as perceived by this site's community, and as a consequence the system is no longer accepting answers from your account ─ that sounds like the system working as intended.

As to your current options, it depends on how bad the answer ban is, and that information is not available to regular users, and it is only partially available to our [elected site moderators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). For one, you should read very carefully the guidance on the main meta site,

> **[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)**

but it does seem like your account is in pretty dire straits as the answer ban will not time out on its own until you fix your posts (which you cannot do given the poor quality of the questions you chose to answer).

Fixing this goes beyond the powers of regular users or site moderators, so I would recommend that (i) you fix whatever answers you *can* fix, and then (ii) you [**contact the Stack Exchange team**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact), linking to this thread, and explain that you are prevented from fixing the remaining answers. If you make a convincing case that you *won't* be answering questions that are liable to get closed and/or deleted shortly after your answer, then I suspect that you have a better chance of the answer ban getting lifted.

Comment: I have read that page for general guidelines on answer ban.. But all my answers are deleted so I can't edit any

Comment: Then, as I said, you should contact the SE community management team and explain that you cannot edit any of your answers, and ask what your options are at this point. I appreciate that you've landed in a situation that's tough to get out of, probably without a full warning that this would happen, but you should also realize that the answer ban *does* correspond to behaviour that this community deems harmful, so you *do* need to show that you're willing and intending to change that behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. There should be a platform for discussion of thinking over simple questions, the concept behind them. I won't answer those type of questions from now